# How to allow set-cookie to be sent in AWS HTTP API Gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, cookies, aws-api-gateway

**Note: This question is not about AWS REST API Gateway, this question is about AWS HTTP API Gateway**

My AWS HTTP API Gateway does not allow cookies to be passed.
I am using

1. express.js app on server hosted on ECS
2. Have set cors as follows:

On HTTP API Gateway:
[image]

On the express.js server I have configured cors in the following way:
In app.js

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true
}));
```

The response to requests are sent in following way:

```
const options = {
    maxAge: 900000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
};

res.status(200)
    .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, options)
    .json({});
```

When I remove HTTP API Gateway from being in between client and server, the client is receiving cookies properly. But when calls are made to API Gateway, response is throwing following error:

```
**Access to fetch at 'https://api.*****.**/login' from origin 'https://cookie.*****.**' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field custom_field_name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**
```

^ How do I resolve this error?

### Here is the preflight request and its response from developer console > network

GENERAL

```
Request URL: https://api.*****.**/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 
Remote Address: [64:ff9b::306:a6f7]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
access-control-allow-headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://cookie.*****.**
access-control-max-age: 0
apigw-requestid: CIlgSiwhBcwEJyQ=
date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 04:45:02 GMT
```

REQUEST HEADERS

```
:authority: api.*****.**
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /login
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
access-control-request-headers: custom_field_name,content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: https://cookie.*****.**
referer: https://cookie.*****.**/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

Read point number 5 about Access-Control-Allow-Headers

That field has the list of allowed headers that you can pass through. You just need to add set-cookie to that list

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: The references and ways you gave works for AWS REST API Gateway. I am looking for the solution in AWS HTTP API Gateway

Comment: I believe they all work in the same way. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html

Comment: aws apigatewayv2 update-api --api-id api-id --cors-configuration AllowOrigins="https://www.example.com"   you can easily modify this command to set allowed headers

Comment: allow origin is not the error from what I can see in the error mentioned above

Comment: Could you post the complete request headers and response header if any for the options request

Comment: Added preflight response to the request above

Comment: I can finalise this as my conclusion. You have mentioned * in allowed headers. Which is not considered as wild card. It's considering as only valid header. Also your request has custom_field_name in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. If possible remove that. Also another try is fill up all the headers (custom_field_name,content-type) instead of *. I bet it should work. Alternatively try with quotes ' * '

Comment: Will try. Gave you the bounty for attempting.